# PHP inheritance - when to use parent?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

In this particular example, we have a parent class and children classes inheriting from parent.

In parent class, we have a public variable called $abc and a method called abc():

```
public $hello = 'hi';

class ABC {
  function abc() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Inherited child class:

```
class DEF extends ABC {
  function def() {
    parent::abc();
    echo $this->hello;
  }
}
```

My question is, why do we use **parent::** to access a method from the parent class, but we use **$this->** to access to the variable, instead of **parent::** as well? I am sticking with $this-> but I would like to know the theory behind that.

Comment: In this particular case you can use $this->abc() as well

Answer (score 0):

```
class DEF extends ABC {
  function abc() {
    return parent::abc(); // here you use parent!
  }
}
```

You use `parent::` to do call a method that belong to the parent but might/was overridden by the child.

Comment: Oh, so it is only used when overriding - I just missed that. Now everything makes sense.

Comment: No, you can also use it if you don't override the method...It clearly tells you're calling a method which doesn't belong to the class, but to the parent (or you want to call the parent and not the overridden method in the child class)

Comment: @user2584228 Or when you WANT to call the parent method, even if the child has one.

Comment: Indeed, I understand - but then, since the variable (not the method) is owned by the parent, why can't I use parent:: to obtain its value?

Comment: @user2584228 There's `static::`, `self::`, `parent::` and `$this->` way of calling PHP *(static or non-static)* methods, each has it's own specific purpose which you should understand.

Comment: @user2584228 Because you can't override a property (variable). You can just change it's value or remove it. Once it's defined in the parent, it exists in `$this`.